# Nvidia and ATI gpu system for three monitors

Tags: debian, gnome, nvidia, gpu, ati

I have a ATI Radeon 2400 XT, and a Nvidia GTX 580 in my debian computer. The 580 has 3 ports, but only 2 of them could be used at the same time. I bought the refurbished Radeon so that I could use another screen, but it was being ignored.
I reconfigured my bios so that the Radeon was the primary display, and the ttys now use that display.
After more fiddling, I managed to get my computer to show the cursor in the third screen when I moved my mouse into it, but in Gnome windows do not move with it. I have also added the ppa xorg-edgers
I stopped gdm, and tried with xinit, xterm and openbox. I had the same problem.
I looked at:

- http://web.archive.org/web/20120906222652/http://en.gentoo-wiki.com/wiki/X.Org/Dual_Monitors
- https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=141041

I could not find anything for debian except for how to setup each individual graphics card.

I am using the free xserver-xorg-video-radeon driver and the proprietary nvidia-driver

xrandr does not detect the Radeon GPU, but lspci and X do.

The gnome cursor passes between them

EDIT:

After looking at https://askubuntu.com/questions/593938, it almost works. Interactions with windows still works, and so does the mouse. However, the graphics do not transfer, and I am left with a glitched screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed this by using `nouveau`, then setting the Radeon to be the output