# How to add xorg-edgers PPA in debian

Tags: debian, ubuntu, xorg, ppa

How do I add the xorg-edgers PPA in debian, without breaking dependencies?

Answer (score 6):

If you're running Debian 8, and you're looking for newer video drivers but you don't specifically need the latest git snapshots, a safer option may be to enable [Jessie backports](https://backports.debian.org/):

```
echo deb http://http.debian.net/debian jessie-backports main > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/jessie-backports.list
```

(as `root`), then

```
apt-get update
```

and you'll be able to install versions of most of the packages available in xorg-edgers (albeit sometimes older versions, but always newer than those in Jessie), *e.g.*

```
apt-get -t jessie-backports install libgl1-mesa-dri
apt-get -t jessie-backports install libdrm-admgpu1
apt-get -t jessie-backports install xserver-xorg-video-intel
```

etc.

These packages are designed to work with Debian 8.

Comment: I am running sid. Are these packages at the same level of xorg-edgers?

Comment: If you're running sid, you don't need backports and you probably don't need xorg-edgers. Sid tends to have the latest releases (*e.g.* Mesa 13.0.3, which even edgers doesn't have), whereas edgers builds snapshots regularly. You really only need edgers if you're developing Xorg, Mesa or an associated library and don't want to build the whole set of packages yourself.

Comment: I am currently trying to deal with http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/337563/nvidia-and-ati-gpu-system-for-three-monitors, so I need to have the latest of everything. XOrg-edgers got the third screen to interact with gnome

Comment: I have added a pointer to your answer in mine, as you are right in saying that this is not the situation needed for most people.

Comment: Thanks, I've qualified my answer somewhat. Your use case was common a long time ago, and worked well with the [Xinerama](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xinerama) extension! But things have probably changed since then...

Answer (score 4):

**READ THE DESCRIPTION AT https://launchpad.net/~xorg-edgers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa**

**Be aware that this can cause severe dependency problems, and may break your X server system, forcing you to purge all of your `xserver-xorg-video.*`!**

For most situations, backports will be enough, see @Stephen's answer for how to do this. But sometimes this isn't enough.

Start bash as root, or become root (`sudo su`), and then `cd /tmp`, so that you do not clog up any directory unnecessarily

First we need to satisfy the dependency for xorg-video-abi-20; an ubuntu virtual package for `xserver-xorg-core`. However, this package does not exist in debian, so we have to create and install it ourselves.

```
$ apt install equivs
$ equivs-control fake-xorg-video-abi-20
$ echo "Package: xorg-video-abi-20" >> fake-xorg-video-abi-20
$ echo "Depends: xserver-xorg-core" >> fake-xorg-video-abi-20
$ equivs-build fake-xorg-video-abi-20
$ dpkg -i xorg-video-abi-20*.deb
```

Then edit apt sources to include the xorg-edgers ppa, and manually install its gpg key

```
$ gpg --ignore-time-conflict --no-options --no-default-keyring --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv 165D673674A995B3E64BF0CF4F191A5A8844C542
$ echo deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/xorg-edgers/ppa/ubuntu zesty main > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/xorg-edgers.list
$ echo deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/xorg-edgers/ppa/ubuntu zesty main >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/xorg-edgers.list
```

Then just run `apt-get update`!