# 'Function not implemented' nouveau clocking

Tags: debian, clock, nouveau

I have a NVidia GTX 580 running under nouveau. It is currently running at `03` (the lowest state). However, when I try to change the clock rate to any setting, including the original state `03`, it fails.

This is what happens (run as root in the /sys/kernel/debug/dri/1 directory)

```
$ echo 0f > pstate
bash: echo: write error: Function not implemented
```

I am running Debian GNU/Linux 4.9.0-1-amd64 (sid)

Comment: Please make your question title more precise. This is nothing that has to do with bash. It is something to do with the kernel/ driver/ hardware.

Comment: "Function not implemented" means that something tried to make a system call that is not implemented on the current system. The caller received the error `ENOSYS`. As for NVIDIA, I know nothing.

Comment: Considering that half of the real hardware/driver problems that get posted on this site relate to problems with NVidia drivers, you should consider yourself lucky if it simply works.  You might want to try alternate drivers to see if they allow what you're trying but be ready to spend many hours troubleshooting your installation if it becomes unbootable (which is likely).

Comment: @GolarRamblar I have updated my title to be more appropriate, sorry!

Comment: @JuliePelletier I have already had to reinstall once! My setup (http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/337563/nvidia-and-ati-gpu-system-for-three-monitors) requires `nouveau` rather than `nvidia-driver`

Comment: @Parallaxbeta:  My comment was explicit enough.  If the drivers you need for it to work don't support that feature, you'll have to live with it, or work on improving them (which is likely a painful task even for experienced driver developers, considering the lack of specs).

Answer (score 0):

This is not a solution, but a workaround in case the GPU fan is running all the time, even without a load on your GPU (NVidia Quadro 2000 in my case).

```
sudo vi /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```

Add and save:

```
blacklist nouveau
```

And reboot your system.

In my case, I am running a headless Debian (Jessie) server without a need for a display.